# ¿Cómo unir dos tablas con lambda?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, linq-to-sql

Estoy intentando hacer un inner join en 2 tablas distintas, mediante expresiones lambda, hasta ahí no hay problema, el problema es cuando quiero que los datos de la segunda tabla se almacenen en una lista de una clase, por ejemplo, tengo una clase así:

```
public class Usuario
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public List<Ventas> Ventas { get; set; }
}
```

Lo que necesito es que con una sola consulta a la base de datos me traiga los datos de la tabla Usuarios y dentro de `List<Ventas> Ventas` almacene los datos de las ventas que tiene cada usuario. ¿Eso es posible?

Comment: Estás usando entity framework ?

Comment: Asi es, uso entity framework y necesito obtener en la clase Usuario los registros de la tabla usuario y almacenar en la lista Ventas las ventas de cada usuario

Comment: Vale, podrías editar la pregunta y compartir algo de lo que has logrado ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marco Jonathan, si te he entendido bien ya tienes hecho el `inner join` de las dos tablas y por tanto te salen los datos de usuario y ventas en una misma "tabla", por esta razón creo que a partir de ahí se puede realizar un `group by` y conseguir tener los datos del usuario por un lado y el listado de ventas de cada uno por otro.

Explicado con un ejemplo, el `inner join` te puede dar algo como esto:

```
Usuarios.ID Usuarios.Nombre   Ventas.IdVenta Ventas.Precio
1           Fulanito          1              36,10
1           Fulanito          2              10,00
2           Mengano           4              80,00
2           Mengano           5              16,00
```

Este resultado sería al que se le aplicaría el `group by` de ID y Nombre del `Usuario` para obtener el listado de `Ventas`.

A falta de definición de la clase `Ventas` y teniendo en cuenta que has conseguido el `inner join` de las dos tablas en una variable que llamaré `listaUsusariosVentas`, tu problema se arreglaría usando `GroupBy` de lambda tal y como te dejo a continuación:

```
var listaAgrupada = listaUsuariosVentas.GroupBy(u => new { u.ID, u.Nombre })
                        .Select(x => new Usuario
                        {
                            ID = x.Key.ID,
                            Nombre = x.Key.Nombre,
                            Ventas = x.ToList().Select(v => new Ventas
                            {
                                // Aquí me invento las propiedades de la Venta
                                IdVenta = v.IdVenta,
                                Precio = v.Precio
                            }).ToList()
                        });ToList();
```

O lo mismo pero con LINQ:

```
var agrupacion = from u in listaUsuariosVentas
                 group u by new {u.ID, u.Nombre};
var listaAgrupada = (from x in agrupacion
                    select new Usuario
                    {
                        ID = x.Key.ID,
                        Nombre = x.Key.Nombre,
                        Ventas = x.ToList().Select(v => new Ventas
                        {
                            // Aquí me invento las propiedades de la Venta
                            IdVenta = v.IdVenta,
                            Precio = v.Precio
                        }).ToList()
                    }).ToList();
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: porque usas `group by` si la idea es unir las tablas?

Comment: Hola Leandro gracias por preguntar, lo mismo no le he entendido bien pero lo que he entendido es que ya ha conseguido hacer el ´inner join´ de las tablas de usuarios y ventas, que lo que no consigue es rellenar la clase ´Usuario´ que ha expuesto, por tanto lo que le falta es agrupar el resultado del ´inner join´ para obtener las ventas de cada usuario. No se si me he explicado bien, intentaré editar mi respuesta para ser más claro

Comment: De todas formas la forma indiscutiblemente más correcta es la que ha expuesto Leandro, además de la más sencilla

Comment: Muchas gracias @JuanRu, precisamente eso era lo que me faltaba

Answer (score 2):

La query linq podria ser

```
var result = from usuario in dbContext.Usuarios
              join venta in dbContext.Ventas on usuario.Id equals venta.UsuarioId into gj
             select new Usuario(){
                ID  = usuario.Id,
                Nombre = usuario.Nombre,
                Ventas = gj
             };
```

Aplicas el concepto de

[Realizar combinaciones agrupadas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-grouped-joins)